# 'delete answer' button opens undelete dialog

Tags: bug, review, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

I was going through the flagging queue today, and hit `delete answer` on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21875793/1069068). However, it opened up a dialog asking for an Undelete vote:

[image]

Could this please be rectified, and can we have already deleted answers removed from the queue? (I'm guessing it already happens and I got cached)